# Visual difference between BitBlt and AlpendBlend

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+, gdi

I draw a filled circle in a square with transparent background and fill color using gdi+ on the DC of a bitmap. Since I need to copy the circle at different positions, so if the fill color is opaque, then I use bitblt do some simple alpha blending:

```
for(int i=0; i<num; ++i) {
   destDC->BitBlt(lx[i], ly[i], lwidth, lheight, srcDC, 0, 0, SRCAND);
}
```

if the fill color is semi-transparent, then I need the pixel-wise alpha blending:

```
BLENDFUNCTION f;
f.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
f.BlendFlags = 0;
f.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;
f.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;
for(int i=0; i<num; ++i) {
   AlphaBlend(destDC->m_hDC, lx[i], ly[i], lwidth, lheight, 
              srcDC.m_hDC, 0, 0, lwidth, lheight, f); 
}
```

Question: why the circles drawn by BitBlt and AlphaBlend look slightly different? I mean the positions and shapes of the circles are a little bit different? I get stuck in this problem for a while, since the draw performance when the fill color is opaque is really important, I cannot simply drop the BitBlt function here. Is any workaround to handle this problem?

A small hint: when I draw using TransparentBlt for the opaque case, the positions and shapes of the circles are exactly the same as using AlphaBlend for the semi-transparent case. But the performance of TransparentBlt is not good enough.

Comment: You are using `SRCAND` for `BitBlt`, try `SRCCOPY` instead

Comment: Thank you. But SRCCOPY is also not working. I can still observe some circles are moving when switching between BitBlt and AlphaBlend. Why could TransparentBlt and AlphaBlend work the same for copy, but BitBlt not?

Comment: `SRCCOPY` is working. You mean it's not working the way you like, or you can't use it here? You should create MCVE to duplicate the problem, otherwise this is impossible to follow. If this is for a game or something maybe you need Direct2D or a different solution.

Comment: I mean SRCCOPY does not help to solve my problem. I’m considering to use Direct2D. Anyway, thank you for your answer.